# A value is not fixed in `case ~ of`

Tags: haskell, case

## My situation:

In my code, a value `xID` seems to be variable in `case ~ of` structure.

```
import Debug.Trace

data I = I
  { iID :: Int } deriving Show
data C = C
  { i :: I} deriving Show

x = I 0
aC2 = C (I 2)
aC3 = C (I 3)
aC5 = C (I 5)

xID = iID x

cConverter aC =
  trace ((show cIID) ++ (if cIID == xID then "==" else "/=") ++ (show xID) ++ " when " ++ (show x)) $
    "Point: " ++ pID
  where
    pID :: String
    pID =
      case cIID of
        xID -> trace ((show cIID) ++ (if cIID == xID then "==" else "/=") ++ (show xID) ++ " when " ++ (show x)) "X"
        _ -> show cIID
    cIID = iID . i $ aC
    -- xID = iID x
```

### What I expect

I expected that when I run `cConverter aC2`, I'll get `"2"` because `2` in `aC2 = C (I 2)` is not equal to `0` in `x = I 0`.

### What happens

However, I've faced the strange result when I run `cConvert aC2` like:

```
Main> cConverter aC2
"2/=0 when I {iID = 0}
Point: 2==2 when I {iID = 0}
X"
```

Why I get `"X"` instead of `"2"`?
More precisely, Why `xID` is `2` when `cIID` is `2`, and `xID` is `3` when `cIID` is `3`?

I think `xID` always be `0` in this code, but does `xID` means something other when I use this in the condition of the case?

## Clear sample

Here is more clear code without debugging message

```
data I = I
  { iID :: Int } deriving Show
data C = C
  { i :: I} deriving Show

x = I 0
aC2 = C (I 2)
aC3 = C (I 3)
aC5 = C (I 5)

xID = iID x

cConverter aC =
  "Point: " ++ pID
  where
    pID :: String
    pID =
      case cIID of
        xID -> "X"
        _ -> show cIID
    cIID = iID . i $ aC
    -- xID = iID x
```

## Point 1

GHCi warns me like:

```
Bug.hs:22:7: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In a case alternative: _ -> ...
```

It seems to be `xID` overlaps `_`.
But why xID overlaps hole?

Anyway, I avoid this problem by using a guard instead of `case`.
However, I could not understand what happens with my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `case`

```
case cIID of
        xID -> ...
        _ -> ...
```

introduces a new local variable named `xID`, which is unrelated to the global `xID`. Further, since it is a variable it catches everything: the branch `_ -> ...` will never be taken.

Use this instead:

```
case cIID of
        xID' | xID' == xID -> ...
        _ -> ...
```

or, more simply,

```
if cIID == xID
then ...
else ...
```

---

About "why" it works in this way:

Consider the code

```
foo :: Either Int String -> Int
foo e = case e of
   Left x  -> x
   Right y -> length y
```

This is a nice total function: it will always return an `Int` whatever is the value of the argument `e`.

Now suppose I add to the code, much later on,

```
x :: Int
x = 42
```

This should NOT break `foo`! Yet, if the `x` in `Left x` is now interpreted to be `42`, then function `foo` will crash on e.g. `Left 43`.

For this reason, pattern matching always introduces new variables, it never performs equality checks with pre-existing variables. To do that, use a guard like `x | x == y -> ...`.

Comment: Thanks your answer very much.
However, I couldn't use `if` because there are many cases not in this code.

Comment: I see. In such case, use a guard in the `case` as done above.